# Uncaught ReferenceError: XXX is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I made a simple digital clock in JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function runMiniClock()
{
var time = new Date();
var hours = time.getHours();
var minutes = time.getMinutes();
minutes=((minutes < 10) ? "0" : "") + minutes;
ampm = (hours >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM";
hours=(hours > 12) ? hours-12 : hours;
hours=(hours == 0) ? 12 : hours;
var clock = hours + 1 + ":" + minutes + " " + ampm;
if(clock != document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML)
document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = clock;
timer = setTimeout("runMiniClock()",1000);
setInterval(function(){
document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();
}, 1000);
}
```

This code works perfectly, but when I open the console I see an error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: runMiniClock is not defined

Why does it show that error message?

[Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mahmoudSarhan/o35arzre/)

Comment: ...because you don't have a function called `runMiniClock` in your demo?

Comment: Try defining the function separately and then having the line `window. onload = runMiniClock()` only?

Comment: @AaronD: not like this, no.

Comment: @Juhana  the first Jsfiddle peace of code was 
window.onload = function runMiniClock () {

but I didn't wrote it because JSFiddle will turn the code of If  Did !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `runMiniClock` is not a global function, it's a local name of the function expression that you assign to `window.onload`.

That `eval`-string you are passing to `setTimeout` is however evaluated in the global scope, where it does not find the function to be called. You anyway should always pass functions, not strings, to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout).

You can fix this by using

```
timer = setTimeout(runMiniClock, 1000);
```

Also, notice that you have two different functions setting the `innerHTML` of `#clock` to different values, you'll want only one of them. And you're missing a few [variable declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), for `ampm` and `timer`.

([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o35arzre/4/))

Answer (score 0):

To be perfectly honest i didn't spend too much time looking into this. But your clock seems to run fine without that setTimeout call anyways?

I took it out in this js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/o35arzre/5/

and the clock still runs and increments appropriately.

are you sure it is needed?

```
var time = new Date();
var hours = time.getHours();
var minutes = time.getMinutes();
minutes=((minutes < 10) ? "0" : "") + minutes;
ampm = (hours >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM";
hours=(hours > 12) ? hours-12 : hours;
hours=(hours == 0) ? 12 : hours;
var clock = hours + 1 + ":" + minutes + " " + ampm;
if(clock != document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML) document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = clock;
setInterval(function(){
document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();
}, 1000);
```